# É possível criar programas com interface gráfica utilizando C?

Tags: c

Se tiver como criar interfaces gráficas em um programa escrito em C, como devo proceder? Estou aprendendo a linguagem C, e não tenho muito conhecimento sobre ela.

Desde já, obrigado.

Comment: Sim, procuro por `GUI em C` que vc acha tutoriais e por ai vai. N sei como que eh em C, apenas em Pyhton ps: GUI = "Graphical User Interface" (Interface Gráfica do Usuário, em português)

Comment: É possível criar interface gráfica para um programa feito em absolutamente qualquer linguagem, no seu computador nesse exato momento rodam diversas aplicações com interface gráfica que foram feitas baseadas em dezenas de linguagens diferentes. Você só precisa achar um programa que crie a GUI, uma pesquisa no google resolve seu problema.